# How to mount a ddrescue image if no partition is recognized?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac, data-recovery, ddrescue

On macOS Ventura 13.1, I successfully rescued a corrupt, not mountable disk (Mac OS Extended (Journaled)) via ddrescue:

`ddrescue -v -f -n /dev/disk3s2 /Volumes/emptyhd/hd.dmg ~/logfile.log`

After some days, i got the "finished" prompt in the terminal:

```
Current status
     ipos:  654704 kB, non-trimmed:        0 B,  current rate:       0 B/s
     opos:  654704 kB, non-scraped:    35840 B,  average rate:  14775 kB/s
non-tried:        0 B,  bad-sector:     1024 B,    error rate:     512 B/s
  rescued:   11999 GB,   bad areas:        2,        run time:  8d  1h 55m
pct rescued:    0.00%, read errors:        2,  remaining time:         n/a
                              time since last successful read:          0s
Finished
```

Double-Click on the DMG didn't work (popup with "not recognized"). I also tried to mount the image with this:
`hdiutil attach -imagekey diskimage-class=CRawDiskImage /Volumes/emptyhd/hd.dmg`
--> didn't work.

I then used the command to attach the image file:
`hdiutil attach -nomount /Volumes/emptyhd/hd.dmg`

Then
`diskutil list`
output

```
/dev/disk3 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                                                   +12.0 TB    disk3
```

Image Info with `hdiutil imageinfo /Volumes/emptyhd/hd.dmg` output:

```
Class Name: CRawDiskImage
Size Information:
    Total Bytes: 11999760071680
    Compressed Ratio: 1
    Sector Count: 23437031390
    Total Non-Empty Bytes: 11999760071680
    Compressed Bytes: 11999760071680
    Total Empty Bytes: 0
Checksum Type: none
Format: UDRW
partitions:
    partition-scheme: none
    block-size: 512
    appendable: false
    partitions:
        0:
            partition-name: whole disk
            partition-start: 0
            partition-synthesized: true
            partition-length: 23437031390
            partition-hint: unknown partition
    burnable: false
Format Description: raw read/write
Checksum Value: 
Properties:
    Encrypted: false
    Kernel Compatible: true
    Checksummed: false
    Software License Agreement: false
    Partitioned: false
    Compressed: no
Segments:
    0: /Volumes/DATA16TB/movies.dmg
Backing Store Information:
    URL: file:///Volumes/DATA16TB/movies.dmg
    Name: movies.dmg
    Class Name: CBSDBackingStore
Resize limits (per hdiutil resize -limits):
 min     cur     max 
23437031390 23437031390 23437031390
```

So how can I proceed from here to access the data in my dd IMG ?

Comment: Why would a file system / drive that can't be mounted, be mountable once you imaged it? Try open and examine the image using a file recovery tool like UFS Explorer.

Comment: Any free alternative to UFS Explorer? `hdiutil` ?

Comment: Im not a Mac person, but I expect you have rescued a partition, not a disk.  This distinction is important as it seems to me you are treating it as a disk rather then a partition, and it does not have a partition table.

Comment: You tried that already, didn't you? All I am saying that if you image/clone a 'corrupt' volume/drive, you end up with a copy of this corrupt volume/drive.